# TypedJS Error: Uncaught ReferenceError: Typed is not defined

Tags: javascript, laravel, typedjs

I'm struggling to get TypedJS working on my Laravel site. I installed it using npm and added the files to my `resources/assets/js/app.js` file like so:

```
/* default code */

require('../../../node_modules/typed.js/lib/typed.min.js');
require('./typedjs');
```

`typedjs.js` looks like this:

```
var typed = new Typed('#header-search-input', {
    strings: ["Los Angeles", "90210", "Vans Spinning Away Video"],
    attr: 'placeholder',
    typeSpeed: 30
});
```

And the complete console error I'm getting says:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Typed is not defined
    at Object.disposed (app.js:47337)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (app.js:13901)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (app.js:13869)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:20)
    at app.js:63
    at app.js:66
```

Feel like I'm not requiring the right file for `typed.min.js` or I need to include others, but not sure what they'd be.

Comment: `var Typed = require('typed.js');`. You didn't assign the result from require to a variable, so naturally `Typed` has never been defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You’re not assigning your typed.js module to a variable. You have `require(typed.min.js);`. You need `var Typed = require(typed.min.js);`